# How to avoid ndk-build compile from the very beginning?

Tags: android, compilation, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Recently, I am reading and modifying code from Linphone-android, which is a opensource sip application. 
Linphone  http://www.linphone.org

I modified some code and want to re-compile it. But the ndk-build will always compile every submodule even it has no changes. And it takes about 10 or 20 minutes to compile.

So, how to avoid this?
Thanks.